# Visual Studio code completion like ctrl+k in netbeans?

Tags: visual-studio, netbeans, code-completion

My question is there code completion for Visual studio like in Netbeans where you cycle the buffer with ctrl+k, when you type something?

Comment: Have you found an extension that gave you similar results to what you wanted?

Answer (score 3):

There's now a nice extension called [Simple Autocomplete](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mksafi.simple-autocomplete) which adds one command `simpleAutocomplete.next` that you can map to a shortcut of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, there isn't a similar feature in Visual Studio.

The traditional Visual Studio autocomplete is using intellisense.

- When you start typing, intellisense may bring up a drop down with suggestions. In that case you can tab to complete using the current suggestion or use the arrow keys to choose another.
- Ctrl-Space (or Alt-Right arrow) will bring up this intellisense menu if it's not up.

I find it does a pretty good job overall.

Some extensions like Resharper or Visual Assist offer their own code completion or other similar features (like Suggestion List for Visual Assist).

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been ages since I asked this question but I found the next best thing to do this. What I would suggest is to use VsVim extension and to use Vim's anyword completion; however, in order for this work, what must be resolved  is the keyboard shortcuts that conflict:

1. Go to "Tools options" in Visual Studio.
2. Then go to VsVim category(alternatively you can search "VsVim" and
   should bring the options) and click keyboard.
3. As far as I know vim deals with this type of completion with these keys
   CTRL+P and CTRL+N so what we do is to let Visual Studio give up
   these keybindings and let VsVim deal with it by Selecting from the drop
   down of the keys(CTRL+P and CTRL+N) and let it be "Handled by VsVim".

I hope this has helped someone out.